# How to export/save a PitchShifted audio file using AudioKit 5.6?

Tags: swift, audiokit

I'm trying to process an `.m4a` audio file I have applying pitch shifting. The thing is, I want to export the processed audio file locally and I can't figure out how!

Here's what I've done so far;

```
import AudioKit
import SoundpipeAudioKit
import AudioKitEX
import AudioToolbox
import AVFoundation

struct TunerData {
    var pitch: Float = 0.0
    var amplitude: Float = 0.0
    var noteNameWithSharps = "-"
    var noteNameWithFlats = "-"
}

class Conductor {
    let engine = AudioEngine()
    var player: AudioPlayer!
    var pitchShifter: PitchShifter!
    var tracker: PitchTap!
    var mixer: Mixer!
    private var musicTrackPlayer: AVPlayer?
    
    var data = TunerData()
    
    let noteFrequencies = [16.35, 17.32, 18.35, 19.45, 20.6, 21.83, 23.12, 24.5, 25.96, 27.5, 29.14, 30.87]
    let noteNamesWithSharps = ["C", "C♯", "D", "D♯", "E", "F", "F♯", "G", "G♯", "A", "A♯", "B"]
    let noteNamesWithFlats = ["C", "D♭", "D", "E♭", "E", "F", "G♭", "G", "A♭", "A", "B♭", "B"]
    

    var pitch: Float = 0


    init() {
        print("Initializing Conductor")
        do {
            player = AudioPlayer()
            player.isLooping = true
            
            pitchShifter = PitchShifter(player)
            
            mixer = Mixer(Fader(player), Fader(pitchShifter))
            
            engine.output = mixer
            
            try engine.start()
            startFrequencyTracker()
        } catch {
            print("catch-error: ", error.localizedDescription)
            fatalError()
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - PitchTap
extension Conductor {
    private func startFrequencyTracker() {
        tracker = PitchTap(pitchShifter) { pitch, amp in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.update(pitch[0], amp[0])
            }
        }
        
        tracker.start()
    }
    
    private func initializeMusicTrackPlayer(url: URL) {
        musicTrackPlayer = .init(url: url)
        musicTrackPlayer?.play()
    }
    
    private func update(_ pitch: AUValue, _ amp: AUValue) {
        // Reduces sensitivity to background noise to prevent random / fluctuating data.
        guard amp > 0.1 else {
            data.pitch = 0
            data.amplitude = 0
            data.noteNameWithFlats = "-"
            data.noteNameWithSharps = "-"
            return
        }
        
        data.pitch = pitch
        data.amplitude = amp
        
        var frequency = pitch
        while frequency > Float(noteFrequencies[noteFrequencies.count - 1]) {
            frequency /= 2.0
        }
        while frequency < Float(noteFrequencies[0]) {
            frequency *= 2.0
        }
        
        var minDistance: Float = 10000.0
        var index = 0
        
        for possibleIndex in 0 ..< noteFrequencies.count {
            let distance = fabsf(Float(noteFrequencies[possibleIndex]) - frequency)
            if distance < minDistance {
                index = possibleIndex
                minDistance = distance
            }
        }
        let octave = Int(log2f(pitch / frequency))
        data.noteNameWithSharps = "\(noteNamesWithSharps[index])\(octave)"
        data.noteNameWithFlats = "\(noteNamesWithFlats[index])\(octave)"
        
        print("pitch", data.pitch, "noteNameWithFlats", self.data.noteNameWithFlats, "frequency", frequency)
        
        let targetFrequency = Float(noteFrequencies[8])
        let pitchShiftRatio = pitch / targetFrequency
        // Apply pitch shift
//        pitchShifter.shift = pitchShiftRatio
    }
    
    private func stopFrequencyTracker() {
        tracker.stop()
    }
}
```

How can I save the result on disk? I think I have to use `renderToFile` but I can't figure out how to make it work.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!